# Replacing an element in recursive nested list python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I want to replace elements in a recursive nested list like so :

```
["not", ["or",["not",["or",["not",["or",["P",["not", "Q"]]],"R"]],["and","P,"R"]]]
```

I want to move the "not" inwards. So basically, "or" gets replaced by "and", "and" by "or", "not" shouldn't be there anymore in the list except for with variables,like ["not","R"] is ok but ["not",["not","P"]] should be just P. please help me out. I have most of the code is ready but I am not able to replace the original array because I am using recursion to move to the innermost element and as I am moving outwards I have to be able to replace the innnermost element with the changes which I am not able to do. Please help me out.

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: Your list format doesn't seem to make sense.  `and` and `or` elements should have exactly two sibling elements, `not` elements should have exactly one.  Your list has a `not` with two siblings and an `or` with none.  You're also missing a double quote somewhere (looks like after the final `P`), but fixing this wouldn't resolve the sibling issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function and `for` loop to recursively replace elements.

```
def clean(lst, string_to_replace):
    newlst = lst[:]

    for idx, elem in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            lst[idx] = check(lst[idx], string_to_replace)
        elif isinstance(elem, str):
            if lst[idx] == replace:
                del newlst[idx]
        else:
            continue

    return newlst
```

And with the list you provided:

```
>>> mylist = ["not", ["or",["not",["or",["not",["or","P",["not", "Q"]]]],"R"]],["and","P","R"]]
>>> clean(mylist, 'not')
[['or', [['or', [['or', 'P', ['Q']]]], 'R']], ['and', 'P', 'R']]
```